# Pass variable Types into a constructor, and return the same type that was passed in

Tags: c#, object, methods, constructor

I need to pass variable object type as an argument to a constructor, and be able to return variable type from the method it constructs. its hard to explain so maybe the code will do a better job.

for passing the object type to the constructor, i tried this.

```
public async Task<BlockData.Block> Last()
{
    return await new AsyncConnector<BlockData.Block>(Connection).Get(
        "/chain/last-block"
        );
}
```

and to receive it, i do this:

```
public class AsyncConnector<T>
{
    NisConnection Connection = null;

    public AsyncConnector(NisConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
    }

    public async Task<T> Get(string uri)
    {
        var response = await Connection.Client.GetAsync(Connection.FullUri(uri));

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
            JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).ToString()
        );
    }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
public async Task<BlockData.Block> Last()
{
    return await new AsyncConnector(Connection).Get<BlockData.Block>(
        "/chain/last-block"
        );
}

public class AsyncConnector
{
    NisConnection Connection = null;

    public AsyncConnector(NisConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
    }

    public async Task<T> Get<T>(string uri)
    {
        var response = await Connection.Client.GetAsync(Connection.FullUri(uri));

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
            JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).ToString()
        );
    }
}
```

the `GetAsync` method needs to work the same way, but for many different object types.

the error i keep getting is:

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'NemApi.DTOs.BlockObjects.BlockData.Block'

Comment: can you just deserialize the string directly without parsing as `JObject`?

Comment: it would still have the issue of not knowing what type to deserialize it to, regardless of if its deserializing from JObject or string.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: i need to return an object of type BlockData.Block but its returning 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' and i cant figure out why.

Comment: You should split up the *await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()* and use some variable and debug and see twhat actually is being Parsed and returned

Answer (score 0):

If you simply use `ReadAsAsync<T>` from [System.Net.Http.Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontentextensions.readasasync(v=vs.118).aspx), it'll convert your JSON to a strongly typed object under the hood.  You don't need to convert or parse on top of it.

```
public async Task<BlockData.Block> Last()
{
    return await new AsyncConnector(Connection).Get<BlockData.Block>(
        "/chain/last-block");
}

public class AsyncConnector
{
    NisConnection Connection = null;

    public AsyncConnector(NisConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
    }

    public async Task<T> Get<T>(string uri)
    {
        var response = await Connection.Client.GetAsync(Connection.FullUri(uri));
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: response.Content doesnt have a method ReadAsAsync only ReadAsStringAsync

Comment: You have to add a reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting` (HttpContentExtensions class)